# 'module' object has no attribute 'get_language' - translation.get_language() vs request.LANGUAGE_CODE ?

Tags: python, django

Today suddenly, I am getting

```
'module' object has no attribute 'get_language'
```

at

```
translation.get_language()
```

No idea why this happens suddenly. any ideas? can I use `request.LANGUAGE_CODE`  instead?

Comment: Are you at least importing `translation` from `django.utils` ?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger yes, already importing

Comment: I've just started getting this error too, but it seems to only be happening when I'm running tests. What worked for me was to import `from django.utils.translation import get_language` and then call `get_language` directly, instead of calling `translation.get_language`. No idea why this worked for me or if this would work for you.